# undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass when using MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongomapper

I set up a new Rails application by following [these instructions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started). I generated a new controller and added `resources :tickets` to the routes file.

```
Hexapoda::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :tickets
end
```

This is the controller (`/app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb').

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tickets = Ticket.all
  end
end
```

I then added a new model `Ticket` in `/app/models/ticket.rb`.

```
class Ticket
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :summary, String, :required => true
end
```

Here's the view (`/app/views/index.html.erb`):

```
<h1>Tickets#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/tickets/index.html.erb</p>
```

Now when I go to `/tickets` in my browser, I get an error message.

> #### NoMethodError in TicketsController#index
>
> undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

I have no idea what's going on. What could be the problem? I'm using Rails 3.2.5 and MongoMapper 0.11.1.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall it was a header on purpose. That's how the error page renders it.

Comment: It doesn't really need to be a giant (distracting) one… you can use multiple `#`s to make a smaller header.

Comment: But that it's a header isn't really relevant. What's in your index template?

Comment: Also, is that really your TicketsController#index code? or did you exclude some code?

Comment: This is really my code. I added the view to the question.

Comment: ad somehting like @ticket = Tickets.all first off to your index and post your rake routes

Comment: @TheIrishGuy added that, but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott here it is: https://github.com/daknok/hexapoda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the latest MonoMapper from Master:

```
gem 'mongo_mapper', github: "jnunemaker/mongomapper"
```

And run `bundle`

Explanation: Rails 3.2.4 added a accessible_attributes method to ActiveModel, but MongoMapper already had this; so they were clobbering each other.

MM issue: [Issue 419](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/issues/419)
MM commit that fixes: [4d35c67](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/commit/4d35c6704a9b6b259a85b339f9ecaf9ca6966602)

Answer (score 2):

Jesse Wolgamott solution above me should work, if it doesn't, you may have something else wrong that is very simple.

For me, this error:

undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

happened because a model file that the controller was calling and displaying in the view had a simple typo in it.  Make sure that when you use **attr_accessible** that you don't forget any of the commas between things.  My issue came from using having new line characters like so:

attr_accessible :address_1, :address_2, :city **<= COMMA NEEDED**
:country, :latitude, :longitude, :state, :zip

Be sure to do what Jesse Wolgamott above me said to do and if that doesn't work or if you are already running that version already, check your model files for typos.

Answer (score 0):

This was giving me quite a bit of headache. I don't have the mongo_mapper gem installed, but restarting the rails server fixed the problem for me.